# How to check whether datatable contains any matched rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am using **Compute** for summing up a datatable which has a condition. Sometimes, there are no rows inside the datatable matching my criteria so I get an exception on Compute
**Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.**

Is there a way to check/filter the datatable to see if it has the desired rows, if yes only then I apply Compute. Please advice.

```
total = Convert.ToDecimal(CompTab.Compute("SUM(Share)", "IsRep=0"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
object objCompute=CompTab.Compute("SUM(Share)", "IsRep=0");
if(objCompute!=DBNull.Value)
{
total = Convert.ToDecimal(objCompute);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, assign the value to an object, which can bedone safely and tested for null values.

Second, use TryParse() if there's a chance it won't work (which is probably overkill in this scenario...  The Compute function will always result in either nothing, or something that can be converted.. But I already typed the code so I'll keep it.  And it's just a good habit.)

```
object oTotal = CompTab.Compute("Sum(share)", "IsRep=0");
Decimal total;
if(oTotal != null)
{
   if(!System.Decimal.TryParse(oTotal.ToString(), out total))
   {
        // whatever logic you need to include if the TryParse fails.
        // Should never happen in this case.
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey it says 'Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'object''.

Comment: What if I use total = Convert.ToDecimal(dtSum)??0; instead of tryparse ?

Comment: I fixed my if statement.  Sorry.  I should have seen that.